# Python Tkinter Event Handler Calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a payment like calculator in Python Tkinter and I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Below codes are all under one class named Menu. These code are just snippets since my code are lengthy. I want an event that can type number 7 in the keyboard and display in the screen. Can you advice me what is wrong with this? And also can I have max width that can display in the screen so that the number will not accept any more number? thank you

```
    def Payment(self, top=None):
    top.geometry("850x315+500+200")
    top.resizable(0, 0)
    top.title("Payment")

    pay.bind("<Key>", self.key)

    self.label_1 = Label(pay)
    self.label_1.pack()
    self.labelImage_1 = Image.open("./images/calculator/calc.png")
    self.labelResized_1 = self.labelImage_1.resize((850, 315), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.labelImage_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.labelResized_1)
    self.label_1.configure(image=self.labelImage_1)
    self.label1.configure(background="#ffcc70")

    self.button_1 = Button(pay)
    self.button_1.place(relx=0.57, rely=0.27, width=80, height=50)
    self.button_1.configure(relief="flat")
    self.button_1.configure(overrelief="flat")
    self.button_1.configure(activebackground="#ffffff")
    self.button_1.configure(cursor="hand2")
    self.button_1.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
    self.button_1.configure(background="#303030")
    self.button_1.configure(font="-family {Microsoft New Tai Lue} -size 30 -weight bold")
    self.button_1.configure(anchor="center")
    self.button_1.configure(borderwidth="0")
    self.button_1.configure(text="7")
    self.button_1.configure(command=self.button_1_handler)


    self.display = Entry(pay, font=("Microsoft New Tai Lue", 36, "normal"), width=11)
    self.display.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.42, width=430, height=100)
    self.display.configure(bg="#e6e6e6", fg="grey", relief="flat", state="readonly")
    self.display.configure(relief="flat")

def key(self, event):
    print("pressed", repr(event.char))
    press = event.char
    if press == "7":
        self.button_1.configure(state=ACTIVE)
        self.button_1_handler()


    

def button_1_handler(self):
    self.display.configure(state="normal")
    self.display.insert("end", "7")
    self.display.configure(state="readonly")
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Please include it in the question. And also you need to bind the event

Comment: @PCM edited my code and added pay.bind("<Key>", self.key) at the beginning. There are no errors, my only problem now is when I typed number 7 it will not appear. It only appears when I click number 7 first then type the number.

Comment: what is `pay`? Key event may work only when `focus` is set on `pay` - and usually it is better to bind it to root window. `top.bind(...)`